# the Durbar without the elephants

Tags: word-meaning

> And then had come the unlooked-for tidings of the imminent proceedings
>   for divorce. And such a divorce! There were cross-suits and
>   allegations and counter-allegations, charges of cruelty and desertion,
>   everything in fact that was necessary to make the case one of the most
>   complicated and sensational of its kind. And the number of
>   distinguished people involved or cited as witnesses not only embraced
>   both political parties in the realm and several Colonial governors,
>   but included an exotic contingent from France, Hungary, the United
>   States of North America, and the Grand Duchy of Baden. Hotel
>   accommodation of the more expensive sort began to experience a strain
>   on its resources. "It will be quite like **the Durbar without the
>   elephants**," exclaimed an enthusiastic lady who, to do her justice, had
>   never seen a Durbar.

from http://www.eastoftheweb.com/short-stories/UBooks/UnkiBlow802.shtml

What is "the Durbar without the elephants"?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's about an obscure historical / cultural reference that would mean nothing to most native speakers today. (So it's not relevant to ***learning English***.)

Answer (score 1):

A durbar (small 'd') was the term used in Mughal India for a meeting of the ruler’s court or council and was adopted by the British to refer to a ceremonial gathering or festival to demonstrate loyalty to the crown. Three were held, in 1877, 1903, and 1911. The Delhi Durbar (capital 'D') of 1903 was arranged by the Viceroy, Lord Curzon, seated on the elephant leading the procession. A large number of important people gathered at a Durbar, as they did at the place being mentioned in the quoted text, except that in the latter place, there were no elephants. Saki's short story ("The Unkindest Blow") was published in 1914, so possibly the lady who exclaimed was thinking of the last British Durbar.

Comment: What does "the last British Durbar" refer to?

Comment: See https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Delhi_Durbar

Comment: @bandaid - "What does "the last British Durbar" refer to?" to the last of the three Durbars arranged by the British, as I said in my answer above.